# Bootstrap 4.1 Dropdowns Not Working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use Dropdowns on my web page (using Bootstrap 4.1). However clicking the drop-downs doesn't display anything.

I've tried using many different code variations but still nothing. There are other things on the webpage, but I've commented it all out and it still doesn't work.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="courseDropDown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Course
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="courseDropDown">
    <a class="dropdown-item">Course 01</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item">Course 02</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item">Course 03</a>
  </div>

  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="moduleDropDown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Module
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="moduleDropDown">
    <a class="dropdown-item">Module 01</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item">Module 02</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item">Module 03</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The above HTML functions as expected (https://www.bootply.com/RvU3dJC3C4) - have you verified that you are including jQuery, then PopperJS, and then Bootstrap's JavaScript asset?

Answer (score 2):

To achieve expected result, include all the required libraries - jQuery, Popper.js and bootstrap

```
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

For below components - Popper.js is required as per the official Bootrap4 documentation

**Dropdowns** for displaying and positioning (also requires Popper.js)
**Tooltips** and **popovers** for displaying and positioning (also requires 
Popper.js)

```
Dropdowns are built on a third party library, Popper.js, which provides dynamic positioning and viewport detection. Be sure to include popper.min.js before Bootstrap’s JavaScript or use bootstrap.bundle.min.js / bootstrap.bundle.js which contains Popper.js.
```

Please check these links for more details

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/dropdowns/

code sample for reference - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/xjbMXP